# Strategy for Requirements Traceability Matrix in DOORS

Tags: ibm-doors

I want to create a traceability matrix in a new module that shows the object ID & text at the top level, then in columns moving to the right the object ID & text for the source of the first in-link, and then it's in-links to the right, etc. If there is more than one in-link, the next source object will be shown on the next line (new object), and the higher level object ID & text just repeated in the columns to the left. Basically, it is the recursive trace analysis layout dxl, but I want to spread out the information over separate columns.

My question is related to the best practices for approach. Is it best to create a new module and write several dxl layout scripts for each column, pulling info from all of the various modules, and then later converting it to text (so it isn't too heavy)? Or is it necessary (or easier) to actually create dxl attributes within each requirements module, and then pull information from there into my RTM module?

I'm likely over-complicating it, but any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Well, one of our assets contains something that looks like your approach:

- script creates new modules that only contains trace information, a "report" module, which does not contain any link to the original "data" modules
- there are some 2 or three columns for each Req Level (high level reqs at the left, low level reqs at the right)

the advantage of this approach is that one can easily use standard DOORS filtering mechanisms to find "holes" in the matrix (requirements which have not been implemented, design elements without requirement etc.). plus, as every report run creates a new report module with the date/time in its name, project progress can be made visible over time, reports to excels might be made.

On the other hand the implementation took several weeks. So, I don't know if this approach would be feasible for you.